# How to highlight the dictionary-like syntax in vim?

Tags: regex, vim

The desired syntax highlight is like this:

**world**: the earth and all the people and things on it **[Hello, *world*!]**

This is a dictionary word, with an explanation after ':', and an example sentence between '[' and ']'. Three parts are highlighted:

1. The word, as is the defined by chars before ':'.
2. The whole example sentence, as is defined by chars between '[' and ']'.
3. The word in the example sentence (to simplify the problem, we may only highlight the first occurrence in the sentence).

I can't highlight all of the above. The worst part is, I can't even highlight a simplified syntax, namely, the same word before and after ':', using the following rules:

```
syntax match Keyword "^[^:]*"
syntax match Underlined "^\([^:]*\):.*\zs\1"
```

Can anyone one please offer a full answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your `.vim/syntax` add a new file for your language, e.g. `mylang.vim`
Use regions to separate the components of your syntax, as below.

You can then link these regions to other highlight groups from your colorscheme (such as `Identifier`, `String`), or use custom colors for them.

```
syn region   mylangHeader          start=+^+ end=+:+
syn region   mylangDesc            start=+\[+ end=+]+
syn region  mylangRow              start=+^+ end=+$+ contains=mylangHeader,mylangDesc
hi! link mylangHeader              Identifier
hi! link mylangRow                 String
hi! mylangDesc                     guifg=#00ff00
```

Once you edit a file, `set ft=mylang` will trigger this syntax highlighting. You can set the file type automatically in your `.vimrc` (based on file extension) if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your answer correctly highlights the word, the explanation for the word and the example sentence, but does not highlight the occurrence of the word in the example sentence.

Comment: Not even using group? The word will only appear once in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following regex: `([^:]*):[^\[]*\[(.*)\]`? See http://regex101.com/r/oO0cD9.
The first match group is the text before the colon, and the second match group is the text in the brackets.
**Update:** in the following regex: `([^:]*):[^\[]*\[(.*(\1).*)\]` the 3rd match group will give you the word in the example sentence, as you requested. See http://regex101.com/r/rA6aT5